# Octave/Matlab High Boost filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, octave, gaussian

I have to use a Gaussian lowpass filter for the blurring step and then I have to improve the sharpness of the result using high-boost filtering.
Here is what I have so far:

```
I=imread('blurry-moon.tif');

A = fft2(double(I));
Ashift=fftshift(A);

[m n]=size(A); 
R=10; 
X=0:n-1;
Y=0:m-1;
[X Y]=meshgrid(X,Y);
Cx=0.5*n;
Cy=0.5*m;
LoF=exp(-((X-Cx).^2+(Y-Cy).^2)./(2*R).^2);

Gauss=Ashift.*LoF;
GaussShift=ifftshift(Gauss);
InverseGauss=ifft2(GaussShift);

%High boost
f = double(InverseGauss);
[m n]=size(f);
J0 = f;
for i=3:m-2
    for j=3:n-2
        J0(i,j) = (-8*f(i,j))+(1*f(i-1,j))+(1*f(i+1,j))+(1*f(i,j-1))+(1*f(i,j+1))...
    +(1*f(i-1,j-1))+(1*f(i+1,j+1))+(1*f(i-1,j+1))+(1*f(i+1,j-1)); 
    end
end

%----visualizing the results----------------------------------------------

figure(1)
imshow(I);colormap gray
title('original image','fontsize',14)

figure(2)
imshow(abs(Ashift),[-12 300000]), colormap gray
title('fft of original image','fontsize',14)


figure(3)
imshow(abs(InverseGauss),[12 290]), colormap gray
title('low pass filtered image','fontsize',14)

figure(4)
imshow(abs(J0),[12 290]), colormap gray
title('final image','fontsize',14)
```

I think I do something wrong in the high boost. But I think I am doing the gaussian filter right?
Can someone help out with the high boost filter?

Best regards!

Comment: Oh okay sorry, i forgot to say that my final high boost Image is only black. But it should be sharpened.

Comment: Is `InverseGauss` correct? Please leave out the bits of code that are correct, so we can focus on the bits that are not. Post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would suspect that `imshow(...,[12 290])` is to blame, and you apply a Laplace filter, which returns positive and negative values, and will probably have very low values because of the previous low-pass filtering.

Comment: A high-boost filter is `img - Laplace(img)`, the Laplace by itself is a high-pass filter.

Comment: Why not apply the high-boosting right in the Fourier domain, since you have that up already? Will help you think about what you're doing, because it makes no sense to suppress high frequencies first, and then boost them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = imread('moon.tif');

% create gaussian filter
h = fspecial('gaussian',5,2.5);
% blur the image
blurred_img = imfilter(img,h);
% subtract blurred image from original
diff_img = img - blurred_img;
% add difference to the original image
highboost_img = img + 3*diff_img;

subplot 221
imshow(img,[]);
title('Original Image')

subplot 222
imshow(blurred_img,[]);
title('Blurred Image')

subplot 223
imshow(diff_img,[]);
title('Difference Image')

subplot 224
imshow(highboost_img,[]);
title('HighBoosted Image')
```